# How can I set and calculate a variable inside a merge statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As title says, I was wondering how I can calculate and set a variable inside a merge statement. If that is even possible.

Example:

```
MERGE TABLE_1 as target
USING TABLE_2 as source
ON (target.USER_ID = source.USER_ID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
         USER_ID,
         CURRENT_CALCULATION,
         CURRENT_CALCULATION_VALUE )
    VALUES (
         source.USER_ID,
         SET @CURRENT_CALCULATION = (select value from table3 where table3.USER_ID = source.USER_ID),
         ... REUSE @CURRENT_CALCULATION for other purposes ...
         );
```

I have tried different kind of syntax but none seems to work.

Comment: I dont think you can use `SET` operation inside merge, but for what purposes do you need to reuse it?

Comment: It's that I have to calculate new values based on the first calculations. And even that calculations is also needed in a new calculation. Basically, do calc, use outcome in new calc, use outcome in new calc, .. About 3 to 4 layers for user_id

Comment: I think you should do it after merge is complete. I would rank them inside merge and then make calculations depending on the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. Without a little more detail I can't be sure that this will work for your situation, but how about simply carrying out this logic before your `MERGE` statement? You could always dump everything into a temp table at the point you do all the calculations if what you're trying to avoid is hitting the same tables twice.

If you did that, you could simply use your temp table as the source for the merge - you may not even need to put it into a variable, as you might be able to include it as a column of the temp table.

Comment: Temp table seems to be the best option. Am I correct assuming this will have increase performance speed?

Comment: It's very difficult to make any definitive statements about what will perform better, because it is very dependent on things specific to you - for instance your table structure, indexes, amount of data, data types, your infrastructure, and so on. Just give it a go - if you find you have a performance problem, investigate then.

Answer (score 0):

Move the logic to *source* part of `Merge` and reuse it

```
MERGE TABLE_1 AS target
USING (SELECT t2.*,
              t3.value
       FROM   TABLE_2 t2
              LEFT JOIN table3 t3
                     ON t3.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID) AS source
ON ( target.USER_ID = source.USER_ID )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( USER_ID,
           CURRENT_CALCULATION,
           CURRENT_CALCULATION_VALUE )
  VALUES ( source.USER_ID,
           source.value,
           source.value + some logic );
```

Considering there is *1:1* relationship between `table 2` and `table 3` based on your `correlated sub-query` used to find `@CURRENT_CALCULATION`

Comment: No 1:1 relation :(

Comment: @RubenCosters - then your query is gonna throw error. Tell what exactly you are trying to achieve.. Add sample data and expected result if possible